# Interior point of convex polygon

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

(Inside points of convex edges)
Suppose that $z_ {1}, \cdots, z_ {n} $ are approximately $ n $ vertices of a $ n $ polygon, $ a $ satisfies $$ \frac {1} {z_ {1} -a} + \cdots + \frac {1} {z_ {n} -a} = 0 $$ Prove that $ a $ is inside the convex $ n $ polygon.

I have tried to translate point a to the origin to make the condition of the question become $$ \frac {1} {z_ {1} } + \cdots + \frac {1} {z_ {n}} = 0 $$
Prove that the origin is in a convex polygon. But I still have no idea.

Comment: This is the Gauss Lucas theorem. If we denote $f(X)=(X-z_1)\ldots(X-z_n)$ then such an $a$ is a root of $f'$. The theorem states that any root of $f'$ is the convex hull of the roots of $f$.

Comment: @VladMatei thanks, I get it.